# Pandas convert multilabeled column into separate encoded columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas series that looks like this:

```
0                                               NaN
1                                               NaN
2                                        red almond
3                                       blue walnut
4                                    RED ALMOND,BLUE WALNUT 
                           ...                     
4051         RED_ALMOND,blue walnut,green cashew
                           ...
4055                                            NaN
```

As you can see, this series contains multi-categorical data in a single column. I want to split this into separate columns such that I can encode the existence of each string (split on the comma). So ideally, something like:

```
   red almond  blue walnut green cashew
0       0           0           0
1       0           0           0
2       1           0           0
3       0           1           0
4       1           1           0
...
```

I can't figure out how. Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

```html
In [55]: from collections import Counter

In [56]: s = pd.Series([None, None, "red almond", "blue walnut", "RED ALMOND,BLUE WALNUT", "RED_ALMOND,blue walnut,green cashew"])

In [57]: transformed = s.str.replace("_", " ") \  # clean your data
    ...:                .str.lower() \
    ...:                .str.split(",") \
    ...:                .map(Counter)  # count how many times each category appears

In [58]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(transformed)) \
    ...:        .transpose() \
    ...:        .fillna(0)

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
   red almond  blue walnut  green cashew
0         0.0          0.0           0.0
1         0.0          0.0           0.0
2         1.0          0.0           0.0
3         0.0          1.0           0.0
4         1.0          1.0           0.0
5         1.0          1.0           1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As the source I used the following Series:

```
0                                       NaN
1                                       NaN
2                                red almond
3                               blue walnut
4                    RED ALMOND,BLUE WALNUT
4051    RED ALMOND,blue walnut,green cashew
Name: txt, dtype: object
```

I assumed that *RED_ALMOND* should be actually *RED ALMOND*. If it is not
the case, replace all *'_'* with spaces.

To get your expected result, first convert each string into a list and
explode it:

```
s = df.txt.str.lower().str.split(',').explode()
```

(Print *s* to see what you got so far.)

Then compute *crosstab* of *s* and reindex, to get *0*-filled rows
for each source *NaN* value:

```
pd.crosstab(s.index, s, colnames=['']).reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
```

The result is:

```
      blue walnut  green cashew  red almond
0               0             0           0
1               0             0           0
2               0             0           1
3               1             0           0
4               1             0           1
4051            1             1           1
```

Note that the order of columns is other (it is sorted), but in my
opinion it is not any major problem.